# Cannot map json type to DTO spring data jpa

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I have a class

```
@Entity
public class Group {
  @Id
  private long id;
  @Column
  private String uuid;
  @Column@Type(JsonType.class) 
  private Info info;
}
```

```
public record Info(String name, String email, String age) {}
```

I have a DTO

```
public record InfoDto(String uuid, Info info) {}
```

I use query

```
@Query(value = "SELECT new com.example.InfoDto(g.uuid, g.info) FROM Group g")
List<InfoDto> findInfoDto();
```

It return error *Could not determine appropriate instantiation strategy - no matching constructor found and one or more arguments did not define alias for bean-injection*

Please help me solve this problem. Many thanks

I change record to class and add contructor, it stll error

Comment: Can you post your whole DTO class?

Comment: It's whole my DTO